# How to get a specific "row" from a DB using JPA (EclipseLink) when the primary key is Auto Incremented?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink, java-persistence-api

Say I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE person(
    person_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(50),
    last_name VARCHAR(50),
    x_cordinates INT,
    y_cordinates INT
);
```

In the past I have used

```
Person person = EntityManager.find(Person.class, primaryKey);
```

But the primary key in this instance is auto incremented, is it possible to get a row back using the other colums such as first_name and last_name to get the primary key along with the other values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use method **createQuery** or **createNativeQuery** of entityManager.

With `createQuery` you have to use `JPQL` syntax and with `createNativeQuery`, you've to use the standard SQL syntax.

For example :

```
Query query = EntityManager.createQuery("select * from person p where p.first_name = :fname");
17.
query.setParameter("fname", firstName);
Person p = query.getSingleResult();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a NamedQuerry like that :

```
@NamedQuery(name="person.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE like :first_name")
```

And can assign a value to "first_name" like that :

```
query.setParamter("fist_name", "%name%");
```

You can read this [documentation](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/named).